# How synchronize code when setState is called indirectly in React

Tags: reactjs

I know that `setState` can be passed a callback to execute after the state is set. However I sometimes have code that I want to be executed *in order* where the state is set "indirectly" several layers down a method call.

For example:

```js
this.makeDirty()
this.doThisAfter()
```

The `makeDirty()` call calls several methods, and one of them is responsible for calling another method that sets a dirty flag on the state. Because of this `doThisAFter` is called before state is set.

I understand that I could try to pass around callbacks all over the place to make sure they get into the `setState` callback argument, but this would significantly (and seemingly can be avoided) increase the complexity and ugliness of the code.

Is there a community-accepted solution for this? One thing I've thought of is instead of using `setState` I would always use a wrapper like `mySetState` that always calls the same callback method, one that looks for the presence of a queue of other functions that can be pre-filled. And then have some kind of API like:

```js
doSyncronously( func1, func2, funcN...)
```

where the `func2...N` would be placed in a queue called by `mySetState` that is called by `func1`.

The problems with this are numerous, and I feel like I'll probably get it wrong. It also feels like I'm re-inventing the wheel or missing something.

Suggestions / comments?

Comment: If you need something to happen synchronously then don't call `setState`. just flip a variable and access it, then when all your sync operations are complete call `setState` at the end

Comment: The above from @azium with possible use of async/await in a try/catch to synchronously  wait for async functions to resolve their intermediate values before continuing on, ultimately setting state at the end.

Comment: Yeah if something *has* to be async then you need to use some type of async handling code style either callbacks, or promises (async / await). That's just the nature of the beast